# Thermal receipt printer problems with auto cut

Tags: java, database, string, printing, thermal-printer

I'm havin a bit of problem with printing a string through the thermal printer...

It's printing properly the content of the string but it isn't auto cutting the paper, it's kept in the printer and not putting it out of it either.

--CODE--

```
receipt = "Table #"+rs.getInt("table_id")+"\n\n"
                   + "Food\t\tAdd\t\tRemove\n\n";

String defaultPrinter = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService().getName();
System.out.println("Default printer: " + defaultPrinter);
PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(receipt.getBytes("UTF8"));

DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(is, flavor, null);
DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();


job.print(doc, null);
is.close();
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should do in the following way:

```
DocPrintJob job = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService().createPrintJob();  
byte[] bytes = {27, 100, 3};
DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(bytes, flavor, null);
job.print(doc, null);
```

Comment: Where do you specify the specific string that you need to print in that one?